# What is the correct usage for persistence using NServiceBus?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

In the documentation it gives the following on setting up persistence:

```
// Use NHibernate for all persistence concerns
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
```

**OR**

```
// or select specific concerns   <------- ??????
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Sagas>();
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Subscriptions>();
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Timeouts>();
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Outbox>();
```

I inherited this code notice that it includes the "`UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>()`" without concerns:

```
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Sagas>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Subscriptions>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Timeouts>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Outbox>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.GatewayDeduplication>();
```

**My question**
*Is it ok to use "`UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>()`" the way our code builds it?*  I cannot seem to find a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Can you provide the reason why you would select NHibernate? We usually recommend SQL Persistence over NHibernate.
https://docs.particular.net/persistence/selecting

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt - unfortunately no, as I mentioned I recently inherited this.  I will take a look at SQL Persistence.  One thing I am noticing is a lot of blocking on SQL side when saga data table is being written too... that is what prompted my looking into this.

Comment: If you want to talk saga design, contact support@particular.net or post on https://discuss.particular.net/ We're happy to help.

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is totally fine.  The first line:

```
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
```

sets the persistence for all storage types to NHibernate.  The subsequent lines "override" this configuration for the specific storage types.  I put quotes around the word "override" because it is overriding specific storage types with the same original value.  In other words, they are overriding NHibernate with NHibernate.

In this example, you only need the first line, the rest are superfluous.  That said, the code as posted should work just fine.

This is fully explained [in the docs](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/order).

Comment: So basically the code is a bit redundant.... thank you for the link... very informative!